# DetailView with data from two other Models

Tags: python, django

I would like to get some advice from the community.

I have recenlty started learning Django and have a question regarding the structure of the application.

I have a URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/2/, a DetailView for my Asset model which also has two card blocks that houses data for two other models Tenant and Service. Check the screenshot below.

[image]

I am generating the above view from the **asset/views.py** file. Code as below.

```
class AssetMultipleDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DetailView):
    model = Asset
    context_object_name = 'asset'
    template_name = 'asset/asset_multiple_detail.html'

    def test_func(self):
        asset_multiple = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == asset_multiple.owner:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AssetMultipleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tenants'] = Tenant.objects.filter(asset=context['asset']).order_by('created')
        context['services'] = Service.objects.filter(asset=context['asset']).order_by('created')
        return context
```

When you click on the Add New Tenant button, I use the below URL in **tenant/urls.py**

```
path('new/asset/<int:pk>/', TenantAssetCreateView.as_view(), name='tenant_asset_create'),
```

This URL generates a CreateView for Tenant. I use the primary key of the asset in the URL to load up only the right asset to the Asset selection field. Please see the image below.

[image]

Everything works well.

I would like to know whether is this the best way to achieve this? Will this be easily maintainable as there are more views similar to this upcoming in the application.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: From code perspective yes this is fine. If you don't want to give people the ability to guess the id then you can use uuid instead of id like : `unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)`

Comment: Great suggestion Ben. I will definitely look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your models look like. Does tenant have a manytomany relation to asset (a tenant can be related to any amount of assets)? Or does tenant have a foreign key to asset in your design (a tenant has exactly one related asset)? Based on the screenshot I assume the latter.
Or do you want an asset to only have one tenant (foreign key on asset to tenant)?

Loading the correct asset from the URL is perfectly valid. You should maybe make asset in the form disabled, so it can not be manipulated.

In the CreateView you could override `form_valid(self,form)` to set `self.object.asset` to the one you need.

Comment: Thank you for your input. An asset can have Many Tenants. A Tenant can have only 1 Asset. So I have an Asset key in my Tenant model. That is the current relationship model. I will look into the suggestion you made on disabling the Asset field in the form. Thank you again.